# Solving simultaneous and determinant given constant value and variable T (temperature)

Tags: programming, linear-algebra

How to solve this two simultaneous equations?

these two equations got from this free energy equation

```
 f=1/2 (T - 1) P^2 + 1/4 P^4 +1/2 α^2 (β) Tmp (T - Tmp) M^2 + 1/4 α^2 (β)Tmp^2 (M^4) + ρ (P^2) (M^2)
```

then i first derivative the equation

`fp=D[f,P]`
`fm=D[f,M]`
which then got the a and b below.

I don't want imaginary and negative answer. In terms of $M$ and $P$

```
fp=P^3 + P (-1 + T) + 2 M^2 P ρ  

fm=M (T - Tmp) Tmp α^2 β + M^3 Tmp^2 α^2 β + 2 M P^2 ρ
```

I already use `Solve[{fp==0,fm==0},{M,P} Reals]` also already use `Solve[{fp==0&&fm==0},{M,P} Reals]` and `Reduce[{fp==0,fm==0,M>0,P>0},{M,P}]` and got a series of solution. already put it in the code and the graph is kinda'weird'

Tmp, alpha, beta, rho, and T you don't have to mind their value. the value of $P$ and $M$ i must use to plot the graph of "M/P againt T" the thing is i did not get the right graph because these $P$ and $M$ value is incorrect which is not simultaneously solve correctly.

**how to copy whole code that i did into this question?
thank you in advance

Comment: Greetings! To make the most of Mma.SE please **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: In your `Solve` command, you have `b==o`, but I think you wanted `b==0`

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) as it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e it arises from a simple mistake (syntax error, incorrect capitalization, spelling mistake) and is unlikely to help any future visitors, or else it is easily found in the documentation. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/10397).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because even with typo fixed, it becomes a misunderstanding of the mathematics rather than Mathematica per se.

Comment: As long as the various parameters are unspecified there is no way to enforce positivity in a symbolic solution.

Comment: You really need to make a better effort on explaining yourself. It's very hard to offer a solution to:"the graph is kinda'weird'". Please help us to help you by writing a [good question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Follow the links provided in the previous comments as a first step, they do contain useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try constraining the domain to `Reals`

```
Solve[{a == 0, b == 0}, {M, P},Reals]
```

You may want to look also into [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html)

```
Reduce[{a == 0, b == 0, M > 0, P > 0}, {M, P}, Reals]
```

Comment: hye @rhermans, i updated the question. how to show you my work?

Comment: Please start by reading this help on how to ask a good question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask
Also read this other question on how to share code http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-should-i-include-code-samples-in-posts